Can a positive LDO be used as a negative LDO?
For typical designs that need a positive and negative supply rail, it seems common to use different parts which are a positive regulator (LDO) and negative regulator.
Is it possible to use a positive regulator for the negative rail as well?  This is by analogy to how a zener+resistor can be used to regulate both positive and negative voltages. But a LDO is a 3-port (or 4-port) device, not 2-port like a zener, so it’s less obvious how to connect it.
Motivation: besides reducing the unique part count, there are some cases in which a negative LDO with similar specs to the positive one is simply not available

Please post specific part numbers, it depends on the LDO

Dear “closed as duplicate” folks: the other question only asks what the difference between positive and negative regulators is, not how one can be used as the other. Spehro Pefhany’s answer below does suggest a very nice topology for just such a substitution, which is also nowhere to be found in the answers to the other question. Please consider reopening

@VoltageSpike For example LP5907 or ADP160. It’s pretty hard to find a matched negative part for that - or in general, for any especially low noise, low power LDOs. I’ve seen real life designs that pair LP5907 with negative TPS7A30… that’s not exactly a matched part by specs

If you have two independent sources, such as two supplies created by two separate windings on a transformer then you can use two positive (or two negative, or any other combination) regulators. The top transformer represents a single transformer with dual secondaries. The bottom circuit employs a transformer with a centre-tapped secondary.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
However when there is a common ground to the supplies then it is generally not possible, since the regulator controls the positive  or negative output relative to a ground terminal. In that case, you need a negative regulator of some sort that takes in a voltage more negative wrt ground than the desired output.

Thanks, very nice answer!  Just to confirm, in the case of independent sources (eg batteries), the two positive regulators works as a positive and negative with no reduction in any of the specs? (eg noise, max current etc)

No reduction in specs except insofar as the two sources are not perfectly isolated. As usual it's best to parallel each regulator in a bipolar supply situation with a reverse-biased Schottky diode (whether the regulator is a negative or positive type).

You can do it with added op-amp (precise solution), or transistor follower in open loop (less precise).
Using op-amp and follower:
The output cannot go close to -12V rail.

Using NPN in common emitter connection:
The output can go close to -12V rail.


This isn't really using a positive LDO as a negative one. This is just making your own negative linear regulator.

The PNP can be replaced to NPN, use rail-to-rail op-amp, and switch positive and negative inputs. You are getting a negative LDO.

That doesn't make it any less making your own regulator. My understanding of the question was that they want to know if they can use something like a 7805 for a negative regulated rail (which you can't, for reasons elaborated on in the answers to the question I linked as a potential duplicate).

Which component in your schematic is the LDO?
